# Operator in C: not greater and equal to.

Tags: c, operators

Just a fast question:

I'm trying to test if a variable is not greater than or equal to another variable.

I have it coded as such:

```
if (f!>=i){
print ("True");}
```

but my c compiler won't recognize it. I can't find it online, is it possible?

Comment: ! is a unary operator. It has to be applied to one thing, so think of what that one thing should be.

Comment: You're going to have to expand on that.

Comment: Um, isn't that the same as `if(f<i)` ?

Comment: @LeeTaylor Yep, that is the answer that everyone below has provided.

Comment: You're in luck! C has a "not greater than or equal to" operator. It's called "less than".

Comment: It's unlikely to be important for your use case, but the pedant in me is compelled to note that `f < i` is not equivalent to `!(f >= i)` if a NaN is involved. A comparison with a NaN always returns 0 (false).

Comment: @PeterO. What does this question have to do with the comma operator? Perhaps you mis-linked the possible duplicate?

Comment: @mah: Guess you're right.  Unfortunately, I can't take back my vote to close.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just change it to `(f < i)` which is `!(f >= i)`.

*Note: this is not the case if either `f` or `i` is `NaN`. This is because `f >= i` will evaluate to `false` if either is `NaN` leading to `!(f >= i)` evaluating to `true` where `f < i` evaluates to `false`.*

Comment: Please note that `a < b` is *not* the same as `!(a >= b)` for floating point types if either value was NaN.

Answer (score 5):

You want to do: `if (!(f>=0))...`

Specific to what you're doing, using `<` makes more sense. My suggestion here is just for a generic means of reversing polarity on any if statement.

Answer (score 2):

Not greater than or equal to is equivalent to less than.

Answer (score 1):

Use the aliter i.e instead of `!>` think in reverse and use `f<i`
and you cant use ! for more than one operator i.e !+= is not valid

Answer (score -1):

You can write it like so:

```
if(!(anyvariablename<0))
```

Comment: This is not correct, as it will be true for `anyvariablename == 0` which is unwanted.